# Bizarre Question Data

Tags: discussion, questions, data-explorer

Here's one for those who like a toasted brain sandwich.

I was running some stats using [data.SE] and noticed a few strange entries in the DB, so I wrote another query to single these out.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/75337/bizarre-question-stats-by-tag

It looks for questions that have an accepted answer value and an accepted answer count of zero.

I would have expected this to return 0 row(s) in all cases, however running this query on the android tag I get 3 results.

At first I thought there was a definitive logic behind it based on question merging.  Upon closer inspection I noticed something a little more curious:

- [#3428187](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428187/can-selenium-test-my-app-for-mobile-safari-and-android-browser) was merged and has no closed date
- [#5215141](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215141/cross-platform-development-windows-mobile-windows-phone-ios-android) was merged but this has a closed date
- [#2228827](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228827/android-jain-sip-sip-registration) not merged, no close date and has a creation date in a different format than the others

I tried to decipher what the story behind these was by looking at them on SO but my sleuthing  deerstalker had been stolen by a klepto-maniacal lolcat while I was buried in SQL.

Can anybody shed some light on what I'm missing other than a tatty old hat and the fish I was going to cook for supper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started with your query and removed the tag selection and added joins for the post answer and posthistory.

That [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/219659/questions-with-answercount-0-and-an-acceptedanswer-or-merged) looks like this:

```
SELECT distinct p.id as[Post Link]
, p.AcceptedAnswerId as [Accepted Answer Id]
, ap.id as [Post Link]
, ph.CreationDate as [Merged on]
FROM Posts p
left outer join posts ap on ap.id = p.AcceptedAnswerId
left outer join posthistory ph 
  on ph.postid = p.id and ph.PostHistoryTypeId = 37
WHERE p.PostTypeId = 1
AND p.AnswerCount = 0
AND p.AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL
```

The result is a table with a non-null value in Accepted Post Link, and/or

For the dump of August, 17th 2014 this gives:

- 103 questions with an answercount of 0 and an non-null acceptedanswerid
- 40 of those questions have no accepted answer. This is caused by the fact that the answer is deleted while it is still accepted, as pointed out by [ughoavgfhw](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/157954/ughoavgfhw)

  Example from [Can initialPlaybackTime do not preform animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572172/can-initialplaybacktime-do-not-preform-animation): [image]
- 67 of those questions have a merge record in the PostHistory table, which means that two posts have been merged

  - 63 of those got the accepted answerid transferred from the merged post
  - 4 questions are merged with posts that point to an now deleted answer that is no longer accepted but probably was accepted when the posts were merged. I can't say for sure because the unaccept events are not stored in SEDE.

  an example is:
  `Post Link                       | Answer  | merged on  |`
  `--------------------------------------------------------`
  `` [Can you shorten the following query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078893/can-you-shorten-the-following-query) `| 3078899 | 2010-06-23 |`

  where post [3078899](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078899) is this deleted answer:
  [image]

Looking at the [Post Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3030906/timeline) reveals that it was accepted on Jun, 15th 2010 and unaccepted (twice?) on Jun, 22nd/23nd